# Nginx configuration on a centos 6.7

Tags: linux, node.js, nginx, centos

Im working on a centos 6.7 machine and I’m trying to configure nginx to serve a node.js application. I feel like I’m really close but I’m missing something. So heres my nginx.conf and below that is my server.conf thats in my sites-enabled directory.

When I go to the public IP address it gives me a 502 bad gateway error. But if I curl the private IP with the correct port on my centos machine I can see the node application running. What am I missing here? is it a firewall issue or maybe something else?

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

sites-enabled/server.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        #server_name localhost;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.xxx.x.xx:8000; // private IP
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

UPDATE: 
I figured this out! heres the server block that worked for me

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    #server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to write a comment but stack overflow does not let me do it.

I am 99% sure that Node.js website does **NOT** need to work with nginx or apache.

If the script setup correctly, the Node.js Application should listen to the port by itself.

Since you did not really say much of your structure, I guess you can just try to access through the public IP with the port of Node.js.